# How do I detect unused imports and variables with ant in an Android project?

Tags: java, android, ant, build

I'm currently building my android project from the project folder with ant like the following:

```
MyProject/
    build.xml
```

The ant command that I use to build is:

```
$ MyProject/ant install
```

In my java code, I have some unused imports and variables, for instance:

```
import java.io.IOException;

String doNothing = "Do Nothing";
```

I'm not making used of the above in my code.  Is there way to detect those from the command line with `ant`?  If not, do I have to use a third party tool?

In Python, I use [pyflakes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) to cleanup my code.  I'm looking for the equivalent in Java at the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) to do this and much more.  It includes checks for both unused local variables and unused imports.  It can be [integrated with ant](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.17.0/pmd_userdocs_tools_ant.html) and you can configure it to fail the build if any errors are detected.  If you are using the standard build structure that is created via the `android` command line tool you can tie the PMD target into the `-pre-compile` stage.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do this if you have proguard enabled. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html